# JOIN Breaking WHERE Clause Subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, date, join, subquery

I have 3 tables in my database.

- **PARENT_A** Has an "ID" primary key column.
- **PARENT_B** has an "ID" primary key column.
- **CHILD** has "PARENT_A_ID" and "PARENT_B_ID" foreign key columns. It also has a "START_DATE" column, which is a VARCHAR (sadly, and I can't change this).

Now, I have the following query.

*UPDATE* - I updated the subquery to be a bit more like what my actual code has. There is an additional restriction on c2 which guarantees the START_DATE is a valid date.

```
SELECT *
FROM PARENT_B pb
LEFT OUTER JOIN CHILD c1 ON c1.PARENT_B_ID = pb.ID
WHERE pb.ID IN
(
    SELECT c2.PARENT_B_ID
    FROM PARENT_A pa
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CHILD c2 ON c2.PARENT_A_ID = pa.ID
    WHERE TO_DATE(c2.START_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy') BETWEEN
          ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH'), -12) AND
          (TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH') - 1)
    AND c2.HAS_VALID_DATE = 1
);
```

This query fails. I get a `ORA-01843: not a valid month` exception. However, if I remove the first join (line 3 of the query), the query runs fine.

I have no idea what's going on. The subquery runs fine by itself and all of the values are in the correct date format.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: Could you add some example CHILD.START_DATE values?

Comment: All of the dates are like '10/07/2011', '03/07/2012', etc. But see above update. I think I've discovered the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly that there are at least some rows in `CHILD` for which the `start_date` string cannot be converted to a date using the `mm/dd/yyyy` format.  Since Oracle can evaluate predicates in any order, I expect that the plan you happen to be getting without the join is eliminating those bad rows before executing the `to_date` and the plan you happen to be getting with the join is evaluating the `to_date` before eliminating the rows for other reasons.  Of course, tomorrow, the optimizer could pick a different plan and the query might work with the join and fail without it.  Or you might find that the query returns the first rows successfully and then throws the ORA-01843 error when you're trying to fetch the rows.

Unless you can fix the data, the best option is generally to write your own string to date conversion routine that returns a `NULL` if the string cannot be converted into a date.  Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_to_date( p_dt_str IN VARCHAR2, p_mask IN VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN DATE
  DETERMINISTIC
IS
  l_dt DATE;
BEGIN
  l_dt := to_date( p_dt_str, p_mask );
  RETURN l_dt;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;
```

Your query would then say

```
WHERE my_to_date( c2.start_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy' ) between ...
```

You can also use this function to find the rows where the `start_date` is invalid

```
SELECT *
  FROM child
 WHERE start_date is not null
   AND my_to_date( start_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy' ) is null
```

Jonathan Gennick has a great article [Subquery Madness](http://gennick.com/madness.html) that walks through this issue in a lot more detail.  It's also a fun read.

Comment: I didn't know Oracle could do things in different orders. My subquery actually had an additional restriction that made sure the date was valid (see question update). So I am guessing it's executing the date restriction before cutting back the invalid date ones. About to try your suggestions.

Comment: +1 Thanks so much for the help. I created the function and it worked perfectly.